# What screen is used in the double-slit experiment?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, experimental-physics, double-slit-experiment

For the double-slit experiment, many websites and videos show models of the screen at the end that can determine the final measured position of individual photons, but I can't seem to find what the screen actually is.

Could someone please tell me what kind of detector/screen at the end of the two-slit experiment can detect *individual photons* positions?

Additionally, what kind of equipment can shoot individual photons?

Thanks!

Comment: Use your wall. See https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/266809/44126

Comment: As is said in the question, I wish to know what detector/screen can be used to detect individual photons - which a 'wall' cannot do.

Comment: Did you mean detect individual photons one at a time or individual photons as a group?  In any case the results are the same.  In 1907 one at a time photons were detected using film .... in modern times we can use an EMCCD camera.  IN all cases the final "screen" is either a camera/film/ or your retina.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean? I wish to know what equipment is used to detect individual photons one at a time, and I don't think a camera/film/retina can do that. However, the EMCCD camera seems very helpful and exactly what I need, thank you, I'll look into that!

Answer (score 4):

If you do the experiment with a sufficiently bright, visible light source, then the "screen" could just be a sheet of white paper that you look at with your eyes to see the projection of the interference pattern.

The screen could instead be a sheet of photographic film that you expose in the apparatus, and then develop afterward to reveal the pattern. The screen could be a CCD image sensor. It could even be a single photo diode that is mechanically scanned through the stationary interference pattern. The screen could be literally *any* technology that you would use to map the intensity of the light that is projected through the slits.

I do not know what they use to detect electrons or other particles for which the double-slit experiment has been performed, but the principle is the same. It's anything that can map out how many particles "arrive" at different locations in space.